# How would I make a grouped barchart for a multiple-answer survey question?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I have a data set involving some survey data that I have been doing some data analysis and data visualization with. The survey data set in question has a couple of "check all that apply" response questions, with the following as an example
> Q3_YN_Num (where 0==didn't select any answer, 1==did select at least one answer), as well as individual Q3X variables for each potential answer (where 0==didn't select that specific answer, and 1==did select that specific answer).

That section of the dataset looks kind of like this:

| Q3A | Q3B | Q3C | Q3D | Q3E | Q3_YN_Num |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| n | n | n | n | n | n |

I have been able to make bar graphs of each individual Q3X variable with my own R code to show whether or not each individual response was selected, like this one:

```
Q3AN <- dataframe$Q3A
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dataframe, aes(x=Q3AN)) +
  geom_bar(stat="count", fill="#782F40", colour="black") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

[image: Basic Bar Graph]

However, I am stuck as to how to combine each of the Q3X responses as their own groups that have multiple bars for the 0 and 1 categories. I'm trying to make a bar graph that would look somewhat like this sketch for a presentation:

[image: Quick Grouped Bar Graph Sketch]

My first attempt was with this code;

```
ggplot(dataframe, aes(x=Q3AN+Q3BN+Q3CN+Q3DN+Q3EN)) +
  geom_bar(stat="count", colour="black") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

However, all I've gotten is this

[image: Very odd bargraph]

So far, I've tried to splice each Q3X response into "Unheard" and "Heard" groups with the following code

```
dataframe$Grouping1[dataframe$Q3A==0] <-"Unheard"
dataframe$Grouping1[dataframe$Q3A==1] <-"Heard"
dataframe$Grouping2[dataframe$Q3B==0] <-"Unheard"
dataframe$Grouping2[dataframe$Q3B==1] <-"Heard"
dataframe$Grouping3[dataframe$Q3C==0] <-"Unheard"
dataframe$Grouping3[dataframe$Q3C==1] <-"Heard"
dataframe$Grouping4[dataframe$Q3D==0] <-"Unheard"
dataframe$Grouping4[dataframe$Q3D==1] <-"Heard"
dataframe$Grouping5[dataframe$Q3E==0] <-"Unheard"
dataframe$Grouping5[dataframe$Q3E==1] <-"Heard"
Groups <-c(dataframe$Grouping1, dataframe$Grouping2, dataframe$Grouping3, dataframe$Grouping4, dataframe$Grouping5)
Subgroup = c("Unheard","Heard")
```

This is where I seem to get stuck, because I cannot seem to produce any graphs that are what I want (or sometimes even a graph at all) based on some of the code I have tried from here.

For example, here's some of the code I have tried;

```
#Attempt 1
ggplot(dataframe, aes(x=Groups, fill=Subgroup) + 
  geom_bar(stat="count", colour="black") + 
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),panel.grid.minor = element_blank())

#Attempt 2
ggplot(dataframe, aes(x=Groupings1 + Groupings2 + Groupings3 + Groupings4 + Groupings5, fill=Subgroup) + 
  geom_bar(stat="count", colour="black") + 
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) + )
```

However, when I've tried the above code or any modified versions thereof, I still cannot get it to work. I am absolutely at a loss and would like to know if there's an efficient way to do this in R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve your desired result by reshaping you data to long format using e.g. `tidyr::pivot_longer` so that you get a column with the questions or items as categories and another column with the responses.

Doing so makes it easy to plot your survey results via `ggplot2` as you could map the new `item` column on `x` and color your bars by the type of `response`:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

# Convert to long format
df_long <- df |>
  pivot_longer(-Q3_YN_Num, names_to = "item", values_to = "response")

ggplot(df_long, aes(item, fill = factor(response))) +
  geom_bar(position = position_dodge(preserve = "single")) +
  scale_fill_manual(labels = c("0" = "Didn't select", "1" = "Selected"), values = c("0" = "red", "1" = "blue"))
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(
  Q3A = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0), Q3B = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0),
  Q3C = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1), Q3D = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0), Q3E = c(
    0,
    0, 0, 0, 0
  ), Q3_YN_Num = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1)
), row.names = c(
  NA,
  5L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I was able to implement this after tweaking it a bit to call the variable columns from the .csv file I'm working from. Thank you so much for your help!